# Extracting the nth element from each list and storing it in a new column

Tags: python, pandas, list, jupyter-notebook

I've a dataframe (called 'df') which contains a column called 'grades'. This column contains a list of grades. The data in this column is of type 'object'.

```
    student_id    grades
0       11      [A,A,B,A]
1       12      [B,B,B,C]
2       13      [C,C,D,B]
3       21      [B,A,C,B]
```

I'm hoping to create a new column called 'maths_grades', which will store the 3rd element in the grades list.

Example Output:

```
      student_id   grades    maths_grade
0       11      [A,A,B,A]        B
1       12      [B,B,B,C]        B
2       13      [C,C,D,B]        D
3       21      [B,A,C,B]        C
```

Whats best was to go about this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use indexing with `str`, because working with iterables:

```
df['maths_grade'] = df['grades'].str[2]
```

Or list comprehension if no missing values and performance is important:

```
df['maths_grade'] = [x[2] for x in df['grades']]
```

Comment: @DanielMesejo - yes, you are right, but it also working with iterables, so if list in column return third element.

Answer (score 1):

`df[‘math_grade’] = df[‘grades’].apply(lambda x : x[2])` will do the job